# How to compress multiple files in to zip file in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have multiple files and I want to compress them as a `zip` file with  Angular 2 framework. I installed `JSZIP` library as well, but unfortunately it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
    var zip = new JSZip();
    var count = 0;
    var zipFilename = "zipFilename.zip";
    var urls = [
    'http://image-url-1',
    'http://image-url-2',
    'http://image-url-3'
     ];

    urls.forEach(function(url){
    var filename = "filename";
   // loading a file and add it in a zip file
   JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
     if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
     }
     zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
     count++;
     if (count == urls.length) {
       var zipFile = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
       saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably your using the latest version (V3) of **JSZip**: If so you can make a slight change to the `If` statement like this and try

```
   if (count == urls.length) {
       zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
          saveAs(content, zipFilename);
       });
    }
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/noelvo/4502eea719f83270c8e9